# Take my Queen, Please

Tags: patterns

I find the conclusion of the following game very aesthetic. White could have won by taking in `d3` or in `f5`, but played the cute `Qe5`, which

- sacrifices the Queen,
- puts Queens side-by-side (in the middle of the board but not necessarily),
- and is the best move (that mates in five).

Do you know any other game with the same pattern?

```
[fen "5r1k/p1R4p/8/5q2/4Q3/3r4/P5PP/5RK1 w - - 0 1"]
[title "Jozsef Horvath vs Gerhard Adensamer, Dornbirn op (1990)"]

1. Qe5+!! 1-0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Adams - Torre](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1143989) comes to mind. It does not fully answer your requirements - some sacs are not side by side, some are not in the middle of the board - but still...

```
[fen "2r1r1k1/1p1q1ppp/3p1b2/p2P4/3Q4/5N2/PP2RPPP/4R1K1 w - - 1 0"]

1. Qg4 Qb5
2. Qc4 Qd7
3. Qc7 Qb5
4. a4 Qa4
5. Re4 Qb5
6. Qb7 1-0
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd forgotten that game. That's a very good one!

Comment: Wow! Is this best play?

Comment: @user1583209 They say so. It is quite a famous combination.

Comment: There's a nice discussion from Edward Winter about this game. https://www.chesshistory.com/winter/extra/adamstorre.html: "one of the most famous and brilliant games in chess history, but is it genuine?"

Answer (score 3):

Another great [game](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1613883) to see is the final move of this 1975 game by grandmaster Boris Katalymov.

```
[Title "Boris Katalymov-Mikhail Kolpakov, Riga, 1975"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "65"]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Nbd7 5. e3 c6 6. cxd5 exd5 7. Qc2 Be7 8. Bd3 Nh5 9. h4 Bxg5 10. hxg5 Qxg5 11. Nh3 Qe7 12. g4 Nhf6 13. g5 Nh5 14. Be2 g6 15. Bxh5 gxh5 16. O-O-O Nb6 17. Nf4 Bg4 18. Rdg1 O-O-O 19. Nxh5 Bxh5 20. Rxh5 f6 21. Rgh1 fxg5 22. Rxh7 Rxh7 23. Rxh7 Qf6 24. a4 Kb8 25. a5 Nc4 26. a6 bxa6 27. Na4 Nb6 28. Nc5 Ka8 29. Nxa6 Rd7 30. Nc5 Rd8 31. b3 Rf8 32. Qd3 Rf7 33. Qg6
```

Comment: Thanks it is indeed a beautiful final move!